# When joining 2 tables one table comes up null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am joining 2 tables on the first table I get all the relevant data on the second table I only get nulls. There are no nulls in either table Can any one tell me why this is happening?

```
select * from apmast
left join apitem
on apmast.fvendno + apmast.fccompany = apitem.fcinvkey
```

Comment: Please show a couple of rows from both tables that you expect should match in a join.

Comment: Your `on` clause is probably wrong. Can you share your table structure and some data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your `ON` that's resulting in you not getting matching records.  A `LEFT JOIN` means that you should get all data from the left table and only the matching records from the right table, or else `NULL` where there are no matching records.  The key to the join, however, is the `ON` statement.  Make sure that `apmast.fvendno + apmast.fccompany` is actually equal to `apitem.fcinvkey`.

Answer (score 0):

here is a explanation on the types of joins just incase you get stuck in the future.

INNER JOIN this will get only the rows that match in both the FROM clause and the JOINING table.

LEFT OUTER JOIN this gets all the rows from the table specified in the FROM clause and only the rows that match in the JOINING table.

RIGHT OUTER JOIN this gets all the rows from the table specified in the JOIN clause and only the rows that match in the FROM clause.

FULL OUTER JOIN this will get all the rows from both tables.

SELF JOIN this is used when you need to join the table back to its self to return data.